# Chainlink Automation is not working for NFT Lottery Marketplace

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink, chainlink-keepers

I am integrating Chainlink Automation in the Lottery NFT Marketplace to play the lottery based on the updateInterval and winner addresses are selected randomly from the NFT counts for each NFT Collection (User can create NFTs in Bulk here so for each NFT bullk Collection winner address will be selected using Chainlink VRF once all the NFTs of an NFT Collection is sold) but Automation is not working so what can be the issue here?

**EDIT:**
I am not facing any error but even though all the NFTs are sold of an NFT Collection and a random NFT Count is generated, Automation is not triggering I mean performUpkeep function is not able to call the playLottery function based on updateInterval time and a user is able to select updateInterval time at the time of NFT Creation and I have stored it in struct so I am getting the correct data but the only issue is that automation is not triggering.

Here's the upKeep URL: https://automation.chain.link/mumbai/93937644591532140693370124396616422475960876625980852389315591504928790618736

Note: I have already registered Marketplace address as an upkeep.

I tried the following code and it should work like once all the NFTs are sold of an NFT Collection then playlottery should be called based on updateInterval using Automation.

Here am I going to share my complete smart contract code:

**Marketplace.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/automation/AutomationCompatible.sol";

import './NFT.sol';
import './ChainlinkVRF.sol';

contract Marketplace is Ownable(msg.sender), ReentrancyGuard, AutomationCompatible{ 

    mapping (address => address[]) private tokens;
    mapping (address => uint256[] ) contractTokenIds;
    mapping (address => uint256[]) contractItemIds;  // Added mapping for contract to itemIds
    mapping (address => uint256[]) collectionsOfSoldItems;
    mapping (address => mapping(uint256 => MarketItem)) public marketItems;  // Updated mapping for collection to MarketItem
    mapping (address => string) collections;
    mapping(address => uint256) private lotteryRequestIds;
    mapping(address => address) public collectionWinners;

    address payable public feeAccount =  payable(address(this));
    address[] public CollectionAddresses;
    address public winner;
    uint256 public feePercent = 2;
    uint256 public getNFTCount; 
    uint256 private _ItemIdsCounter;    
        ChainlinkVRF public vrfContract;

    event TokenCreated(address, address);

     struct MarketItem {
        uint256 itemId;
        address nftContract;
        uint256 tokenId;
        address payable seller;
        address payable owner;
        uint256 price;
        bool sold;
    }

    event MarketItemCreated(
        uint256 indexed itemId,
        address indexed nftContract,
        uint256 indexed tokenId,
        address seller,
        address owner,
        uint256 price
    );

      event Bought(
        uint256 itemId,
        address indexed nft,
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint256 price,
        address indexed seller,
        address indexed buyer
    );
   struct CollectionInfo {
     uint256 updateInterval;
     uint256 lastTimeStamp;
     uint256 winnerPercentage;
     bool allSold;
   }
  mapping(address => CollectionInfo) public collectionInfo;


    function createToken(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 updateInterval,
        uint256 winnerPercentage
    ) public {
        address _address = address(new NFT(name, symbol, updateInterval, winnerPercentage));
        collectionInfo[_address] = CollectionInfo({
        updateInterval: updateInterval,
        lastTimeStamp: block.timestamp,
        winnerPercentage: winnerPercentage,
        allSold: false
    });
        uint256 count = 0;
        tokens[msg.sender].push(_address);
        CollectionAddresses.push(_address);
        count++;
        emit TokenCreated(msg.sender, _address);
        // addNFTConsumer(subscriptionId, _address);
    }
    // function addNFTConsumer(uint64 subscriptionId, address tokenAddress) public  {
    //         VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinator).addConsumer(subscriptionId, tokenAddress);
    // }
    
       function setVRFContract(address _vrfContract) external onlyOwner{
        vrfContract = ChainlinkVRF(_vrfContract);
       }
   function bulkMintERC721(
    address tokenAddress,
    uint256 start,
    uint256 end
) public {
    uint256 count = 0;
    for (uint256 i = start; i < end; i++) {
        uint256 tokenId = NFT(tokenAddress).safeMint(msg.sender);
        contractTokenIds[tokenAddress].push(tokenId);
        count++;
    }
    getNFTCount = count;
}
 function createMarketItem(
    address nftContractAddress,
    uint256 start,
    uint256 end,
    uint256 price
) public nonReentrant {
    for (uint256 i = start; i < end; i++) {
        uint256 tokenId = contractTokenIds[nftContractAddress][i];
        uint256 itemId = i;  
        marketItems[nftContractAddress][itemId] = MarketItem(
                itemId,
                nftContractAddress,
                tokenId,
                payable(msg.sender),
                payable(address(0)),
                price,
                false
            );

        IERC721(nftContractAddress).transferFrom(
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            tokenId
        );
        contractItemIds[nftContractAddress].push(itemId);
        emit MarketItemCreated(
            itemId,
            nftContractAddress,
            tokenId,
            msg.sender,
            address(0),
            price
        );
    }
}


  function purchaseItem(address nftContract, uint256 tokenId) external payable nonReentrant {
    uint256 _totalPrice = getTotalPrice(nftContract, tokenId);
        MarketItem storage item = marketItems[nftContract][tokenId];

    require(msg.value >= _totalPrice, "not enough ether to cover item price and market fee");
    require(!item.sold, "item already sold");

    // Transfer funds to the seller
    (bool successSeller, ) = item.seller.call{value: item.price}("");
    require(successSeller, "Transfer to seller failed");

    // Transfer funds to the fee account
    (bool successFee, ) = feeAccount.call{value: _totalPrice - item.price}("");
    require(successFee, "Transfer to fee account failed");

    item.sold = true; 

    // Use 'call' to transfer the NFT
    (bool successTransfer, ) = address(IERC721(nftContract)).call(
        abi.encodeWithSignature("transferFrom(address,address,uint256)", address(this), msg.sender, tokenId)
    );
    require(successTransfer, "NFT transfer failed");

    marketItems[nftContract][tokenId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
    collectionsOfSoldItems[nftContract].push(tokenId);
    if (collectionsOfSoldItems[nftContract].length == getNFTCount) {
        CollectionInfo storage info = collectionInfo[nftContract];
        info.allSold = true;
    }
    emit Bought(item.itemId, nftContract, item.tokenId, item.price, item.seller, msg.sender);
}
function callRequestRandomWords(address tokenAddress) public returns(uint256) {
    uint256 nftCount = contractTokenIds[tokenAddress].length;
    uint256 requestId = vrfContract.requestRandomWords(nftCount, tokenAddress);
    lotteryRequestIds[tokenAddress] = requestId;
    return requestId;
}
 function getRequestIdForCollection(address collectionAddress)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return vrfContract.getRequestIdForCollection(collectionAddress);
    }

function getRequestStatus(uint256 _requestId) public view returns(bool, uint256){
       return vrfContract.getRequestStatus(_requestId);
}
 function setCollectionUri(address collectionContract, string memory uri) public{
            collections[collectionContract] = uri;
    }

function getCollectionUri(address collectionContract) public view returns(string memory){
       return collections[collectionContract];
    }

function getAllTokenId(address tokenContractAddress) public view returns (uint[] memory){
    uint[] memory ret = new uint[](getNFTCount);
    for (uint i = 0; i < getNFTCount; i++) {
        ret[i] = contractTokenIds[tokenContractAddress][i];
    } 
    return ret;
}
  
  function getAllContractAddresses() public view returns(address[] memory) {
   return CollectionAddresses;
  }
  
  function getAllSoldItems(address nftContract) external view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        return collectionsOfSoldItems[nftContract];
    }

  function getTotalPrice(address nftContract, uint256 tokenId) public view returns (uint256) {
        return ((marketItems[nftContract][tokenId].price * (100 + feePercent)) / 100);
    }
// function callRequestRandomWords(address tokenAddress) public returns(uint256) {
//     return NFT(tokenAddress).requestRandomWords();
//     }
//  function callGetRequestStatus(address tokenAddress, uint256 _requestId) public view returns(bool, uint256[] memory) {
//      return NFT(tokenAddress).getRequestStatus(_requestId);
//    }


function playLottery(address collectionAddress, uint256 requestId) internal {
    require(lotteryRequestIds[collectionAddress] == requestId, "Invalid request ID");
    CollectionInfo storage info = collectionInfo[collectionAddress];
    require(info.allSold, "Not all NFTs are sold");

    (bool fulfilled, uint256 randomTokenNumber) = getRequestStatus(requestId);
    require(fulfilled, "Random number not fulfilled");
    winner = getWinnerAddress(collectionAddress, requestId);
    collectionWinners[collectionAddress] = winner;

    uint256 totalPrice = getTotalPrice(collectionAddress, randomTokenNumber);
    uint256 winnerAmount = (totalPrice * info.winnerPercentage) / 100;
    uint256 creatorAmount = totalPrice - winnerAmount;

    // Deduct fees from the winner and creator amounts
    uint256 winnerFinalAmount = winnerAmount - ((winnerAmount * feePercent) / 100);
    uint256 creatorFinalAmount = creatorAmount - ((creatorAmount * feePercent) / 100);

    payable(msg.sender).transfer(creatorFinalAmount);
    feeAccount.transfer((totalPrice * feePercent) / 100);
    payable(winner).transfer(winnerFinalAmount);    

    // Reset for the next lottery
    info.lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
    info.allSold = false;
}
  function getWinnerAddress(address collectionAddress, uint256 requestId) public view returns (address) {
    (bool fulfilled, uint256 randomTokenNumber) = getRequestStatus(requestId);

    require(fulfilled, "Random number not fulfilled");

    MarketItem storage winningItem = marketItems[collectionAddress][randomTokenNumber];

    return winningItem.owner;
}

function getCollectionWinner(address collectionAddress) external view returns (address) {
        return collectionWinners[collectionAddress];
    }
function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData)
    external
    view
    override
    returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData)
{
    address collectionAddress = abi.decode(checkData, (address));
    CollectionInfo memory info = collectionInfo[collectionAddress];
    upkeepNeeded = (block.timestamp - info.lastTimeStamp) > info.updateInterval && info.allSold;
    // Encode the requestId in the performData for later use in performUpkeep
    performData = abi.encode(lotteryRequestIds[collectionAddress]);
    
    return (upkeepNeeded, performData);
}

function performUpkeep(bytes calldata performData) external override {
    uint256 requestId = abi.decode(performData, (uint256));
    address collectionAddress = getCollectionAddress(requestId);
    playLottery(collectionAddress, requestId);
}


// Helper function to retrieve the collection address from the requestId
// function getCollectionAddress(uint256 requestId) internal view returns (address) {
//     // You may need to adapt this based on how requestId is associated with the collection
//     for (uint256 i = 0; i < CollectionAddresses.length; i++) {
//         if (lotteryRequestIds[CollectionAddresses[i]] == requestId) {
//             return CollectionAddresses[i];
//         }
//     }
//     revert("Collection not found for the requestId");
// }
function getCollectionAddress(uint256 requestId) public view returns (address) {
    // You may need to adapt this based on how requestId is associated with the collection
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < CollectionAddresses.length; i++) {
        if (lotteryRequestIds[CollectionAddresses[i]] == requestId) {
            return CollectionAddresses[i];
        }
    }
    revert("Collection not found for the requestId");
}
  function onERC721Received(address, address, uint256, bytes calldata) external pure returns (bytes4) {
        return IERC721Receiver.onERC721Received.selector;
      }
 function withdrawFunds(uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
        uint256 currentBalance = address(this).balance;
        require(amount <=  currentBalance, "Insufficient funds");
        currentBalance -= amount;
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
    }
      receive() external payable {}

}

**NFT.sol** 
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721{

    uint256 private _tokenIdCounter;
    uint256 public immutable interval;
    uint256 public lastTimeStamp;
    uint256 public winnerPercentage;

      constructor(
           string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        uint256 _updateInterval,
        uint256 _winnerPercentage
    

        )
        ERC721(_name, _symbol)
    {
        interval = _updateInterval;
        lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        winnerPercentage = _winnerPercentage;
     
    }
  
   function safeMint (address to) public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter;
           _safeMint(to, tokenId);    
          _tokenIdCounter++;
          return tokenId;
    }
}
**ChainlinkVRF.sol** 
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
contract ChainlinkVRF is  VRFConsumerBaseV2{
    uint256 private _tokenIdCounter;
    uint32 public callbackGasLimit = 100000;
    uint16 public requestConfirmations = 3;
    uint32 public numWords = 1;
    uint64 s_subscriptionId;
    bytes32 keyHash;
    uint256 public s_randomTokenCount;

    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface COORDINATOR;


    event RequestSent(uint256 requestId, uint32 numWords);
    event RequestFulfilled(uint256 requestId, uint256 randomtokenCount);
    event ReturnedRandomAddress(uint256 randomtokenCount);

     struct RequestStatus {
           bool fulfilled;
    bool exists;
    uint256 nftCount; // NFT count at the time of the request
    uint256 randomTokenNumber; // The resulting random number
    }
    mapping(uint256 => RequestStatus)
        public s_requests; /* requestId --> requestStatus */
    mapping(address => uint256) public collectionToRequestId;

    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToRequestId;
     // past requests Id.
    uint256[] public requestIds;
    uint256 public lastRequestId;
    address marketplaceOwner;
 constructor(
        uint64 _subscriptionId,
        bytes32 _keyHash,
        address _vrfCoordinator
        )
        VRFConsumerBaseV2(_vrfCoordinator)

    {
    
        s_subscriptionId = _subscriptionId;
        keyHash = _keyHash;
        COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(_vrfCoordinator );
    }

    function getRequestStatus(
        uint256 _requestId
    ) external view returns (bool fulfilled, uint256 randomTokenNumber) {
        require(s_requests[_requestId].exists, "request not found");
        RequestStatus memory request = s_requests[_requestId];
        return (request.fulfilled, request.randomTokenNumber);
    }


    function requestRandomWords(uint256 nftCount, address tokenAddress)
        external 
        returns (uint256 requestId)
    {
        requestId = COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
            keyHash,
            s_subscriptionId,
            requestConfirmations,
            callbackGasLimit,
            numWords
        );
        s_requests[requestId] = RequestStatus({
        nftCount: nftCount,
        randomTokenNumber: 0,
        exists: true,
        fulfilled: false
        });
        s_randomTokenCount = nftCount;
        requestIds.push(requestId);
        lastRequestId = requestId;
        collectionToRequestId[tokenAddress] = requestId;
        emit RequestSent(requestId, numWords);
        return requestId;
    }
    function getRequestIdForCollection(address collectionAddress)
        external
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return collectionToRequestId[collectionAddress];
    }
   
  function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 _requestId,
        uint256[] memory _randomWords
    ) internal override {
        require(s_requests[_requestId].exists, "request not found");
        s_requests[_requestId].fulfilled = true;
         uint256 nftCount = s_requests[_requestId].nftCount;
    uint256 randomTokenNumber = _randomWords[0] % nftCount;
    s_requests[_requestId].randomTokenNumber = randomTokenNumber;
    emit RequestFulfilled(_requestId, randomTokenNumber);

    }
}
    

     I can get all sold items as true in a struct as all the NFTs are sold and requestId for a particular collection but the issue is only automation is not triggering.
Thank you!
```

Comment: your codes look good. What is your automation subscription url? Can automation detect the result from `checkUpkeep`? Or automation fails to trigger `peformUpkeep`? Can you edit your question to share your complete smart contract and describe the issues you have with automation?

Comment: Hey @FrankKong, Thanks for responding. I have edited my question.

Comment: can you try if you can manually call the checkUpkeep with checkData and get return value as true?

Comment: I tried it manually and it is working as expected but it is not working by registering an UpKeep

Comment: @MahimaThacker I note your Tx is reverting during performUpkeep
https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x6ada5fe3a2d4aa125f2b4dc10aed5c8b2a6cbbbc99d00a4c4bd8cbbd4b6ab837

In your upkeep configuration page (https://automation.chain.link/mumbai/93937644591532140693370124396616422475960876625980852389315591504928790618736) I cant see that you're passing the checkdata bytes? As per your smart contract code this gets decoded in checkUpkeep and used later in performUpkeep right?  So maybe you need to pass the collectionAddress in your upkeep config?